Installed wrong drivers for Epson printer
I have a Kubuntu 22.04 and I had an existing Epson XP-235 printer already working fine with a Windows desktop.
I connected the Epson printer to Kubuntu, it was detected an provided a list of drivers. I wasn't sure which exact to choose so I think I picked the wrong one from the list so now the printer seems to malfunction as the lights blink it doesn't print and additionally I can't use it from the Windows desktop anymore either.
Is it possible to use a printer from both Windows and Kubuntu and how can I pick the right drivers? How can I fix this issue now?

Why the downvote? Is the question not suitable for this SE?

Hi Jim. It's unlikely Kubuntu caused this because, with rare exceptions, the Linux driver should not affect the Windows one. The exception being if Kubuntu somehow changed something inside the printer. Frankly, if you power the printer on and off it might help.
All this said, this question should probably be asked on the SuperUser SE. Cheers!
